# Wrapfigure wraps and then floats again

Tags: wrapfigure

(My first post - please let me know if/how I can improve my questions in the future!)
(Modified to include a complete example file)

The code in question is automatically generated via a script. There are about a dozen other identical code snippets (only the file names change). Three of the twelve code segments demonstrate an unexpected additional indentation at the end of the section.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside,american]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}                               % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                                  % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ...
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[verbose]{wrapfig}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xkeyval,ifthen,url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        annotation,
        loadfiles=true % this forces load of external annotations - based on naming convention
]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\input{bibs_index.tex}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}%
\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
\bibhyperref{#1}}
\savebibmacro{cite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
  \restorebibmacro{cite}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\input{fonts.tex}
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setlist{nosep} %tighten up lists

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\section{The Contributors}
\subsection{Jane~Smith}
\textsf{Washington, DC, USA}
\par \setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth} \centering \includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{bios/iglazer.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textsf{ \input{random.txt} }
\WFclear
\subsubsection{Recommendations}\begin{enumerate}
\item \cite{Clippinger2007}
\item \cite{Richer2017}
\end{enumerate}\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.2pt}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Odd indentation]

Comment: wrapfigure doesn't have that much documentation but the one thing it does document is that it doesn't work near lists... It's usually possible to do something but it would be much easier to answer if you provided a complete small document that showed the problem, not a fragment. (you can use `example-image` as the image as it is available for such tests.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (and the welcome!) Hopefully the revised post is better (but please tell me if I can improve it).

Comment: All you need to do is add a `%` immediately after `\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}`.  Wrapfigure needs to start in vmode, either between paragraphs or at the end of a line.  Almost every time you end a line with `}` you add an extra space, taking you out of vmode.

Comment: Tried that (made sure there were no spaces between `0pt}` and `%`). Did that for every line that had a space after a command as well, just on general principles. No change to the output.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to not have a float. Here is a possibility with the plain text macro package `insbox`, which defines `\InsertBoxL` and `\InsertBoxR` commands, with two mandatory arguments: the number of lines at the beginning of a paragraph which will remain untouched, and the box to be inserted. Also a final optional argument: the number of supplementary lines which should be shortened, in case the calculations of TeX would be wrong.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\input{insbox}
\makeatletter
\@InsertBoxMargin = 10pt
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Ian~Glazer} \textsf{Washington, DC, USA} \smallskip

\InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{PepeLePew}}[-1]
\sffamily \lipsum[2-10]

\subsubsection{Recommendations}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \cite{Clippinger2007}
    \item \cite{Richer2017}
    \end{enumerate}\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.2pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Can't quite get that to work. (and can't figure out how to better format the comments so this is readable - grr)   /usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def))
Runaway argument?
{\includegraphics [width=0.18\textwidth ]{bios/iglazer.jpg}[-1] \sffamily \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \InsertBoxL.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> anbib-test.tex

Comment: Can you compile my code? (add the `[demo]`option to graphicx, as I suppose you don't have my image)

Comment: Yes. When I substitute a new image in the \InsertBoxL, is when I get the error. No other changes made. My line: \InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{bios/iglazer.jpg}[-1]

Comment: AhHA! Found it! Missing a closing curly bracket! Score!!!

Comment: All but one of the entries now format correctly and all entries are automatically generating. The one that is not generating properly in my production file seems identical to the others but shows a mostly blank page then text and image partially overlapped. The code for that entry works when extracted into a test file. I need a drink.

Comment: Perhaps a problem of bounding box? To test, nest your include graphics in a `\fbox`.

Comment: Like this? `\InsertBoxL{0}{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{bios/cscholefield.jpg}}}`

Comment: Yes, exactly ${}$.

Comment: No change. I added the `\fbox` to the entries immediately before and after in case there was some weird inheritance going on. Absolutely nothing interesting in the log file to help.

Comment: And the bounding box is not larger than the real image?

Comment: @HeatherFlanagan -- You say that all but one instance of the insertion works.  It sounds like that may be occurring at a page break.  (Such things can get a bit squirrelly at page breaks.)  Try adding a forced page break (`\newpage` perhaps) at the last paragraph break before the insertion.  I'm not able to test; this is just an educated guess.

Comment: @Bernard, how/why would the bounding box for this one image (which is roughly the same size than all the other images in this document) be different? I'm not sure how to check about the actual size of the bounding box - I'll go look that up.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, unfortunately, the `\newpage` did not help.

Comment: The [document](https://github.com/IDPros/anno-biblio/blob/bib-edits/anbib.pdf) itself, with the tex revised to use the insbox layout, is public on GitHub if folks want a better idea of what I'm seeing. Page 4-5.

Comment: Did you try `\enlargethispage{n\baselineskip}` (1 or 2 might be enough)?

Answer (score 1):

The package `lettrine` is mainly designed for dropped capitals,  but it also allow put a left wrapped image at the start of a paragraph, with a very simple code.  Moreover, `\lettrine` have several options that allow a fine-tuning of the image position.

Unfortunately for this case, it is designed for a single paragraph, with no indentation of the  first line,. But for the fist problem is easy make a `\fakepar` and for the second the `\lettrine` options are enough, as show the example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}        
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for dummy text
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\parskip1em
\parindent2em

\def\fakepar{\hfill\mbox{}\vspace{\parskip}\newline\mbox{}\hspace{\parindent}}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{Robert Conway}
Shangri-La, Lost Horizons, Kunlun Mountains\par\bigskip

\lettrine[
lines=13,
lraise=-.1,
findent=5em,
nindent=-2em,
lhang=-.2,
depth=1,
image=true]{example-image-golden-upright}{}% 
\lipsum[1][1-4] 
\lipsum[2][1-4]\fakepar
\lipsum[3-7]

\end{document}
```